# sed subsitution line by line with contents from another file

Tags: bash, sed

I am automating some tasks.

I would like to know if it is possible to substitute each line from a different file in between
mentor will be required and the date in the source file

Each line is structured as

```
blahblahblah....string_I_need_to_replace....blahblahblah
```

I used sed commands to extract the strings I need to replace because it needs to go from `data1,data2,data3,` to `data1-description; data2 - description; data3 - description`

`data1,data2,data3` are not always the same and only `data1` is guaranteed to be in the line

this line

```
blahblah....mentor will be required.",Collaboration,Analytical Skills,Integrity & Ethics,3/1/17 20:04 ... blahblah
```

needs to be

```
blahblah....mentor will be required.","Collaboration-description;Analytical Skills - description; Integrity & Ethics - description " 3/1/17 20:04 ....blah blah blah
```

on the first line my parsed file contains

```
Collaboration-description;Analytical Skills - description; Integrity & Ethics - description
```

I have used sed commands to extract the inner part `Collaboration-description;Analytical Skills - description; Integrity & Ethics - description` on each line in a separate file.

There is many `,` and `;` and numbers before and after the data I am interested in changing and the count varies by line so replace the nth , is going to be an issue there are up to three , when data2 and data3 are empty is reason for the `outfile2` and `outfile3` processing which removes last ,

```
#!/bin/bash
unset LANG
cat export-14.csv | sed -n -e 's/^.*mentor will be required.",//p' > outfile
sed 's/[0-9].*//'  outfile > outfile2
sed 's/,$//'       outfile2 > outfile3
sed 's/,$//'       outfile3 > outfile4
sed 's/,/;/g'      outfile4 >outfile5
sed 's/Analytical SKills/Analytical Skills - identifying and solving problems/' outfile5 > outfile6
sed 's/Adaptability/Adaptability - embracing opportunities for improvement and resilience/' outfile6 > outfile7
sed 's/Collaboration/Collaboration - working with others/' outfile7 > outfile8
sed 's/Technology/Technology - employing current and emerging software\/tools/' outfile8 > outfile9
sed "s/Communication/Communication - articulating one\'s self/g" outfile9 > outfile10
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here. That said, `sed -i -e '...' -e '...' -e '...'` will be better performing.

Comment: Thanks my question was buried and hard to see                                         I put actual question near the top                                                                      "I would like to know if it is possible to substitute each line from a different file in between mentor will be required and the date in the source file"

Comment: came up with a ugly non flexible solution ,date in the form of ,m/dd/year only occurs one time each line and mentor will be required is before the data I need changed instead of making separate file i use mentor... and the ,date as markers and replace everything inside. Works but UGLY

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question `I would like to know if it is possible to substitute each line from a different file in between mentor will be required and the date in the source file` is **yes** but without concise, testable sample input and expected output that's really as much info as can be provided.

Having said that - your current series of sed scripts can be rewritten as a single awk script:

```
awk 'sub(/^.*mentor will be required.",/,"") {
    sub(/,{1,2}[0-9].*/,"")
    gsub(/,/,";")
    sub(/Analytical SKills/,"Analytical Skills - identifying and solving problems")
    sub(/Adaptability/,"Adaptability - embracing opportunities for improvement and resilience")
    sub(/Collaboration/,"Collaboration - working with others")
    sub(/Technology/,"Technology - employing current and emerging software/tools")
    sub(/Communication/,"Communication - articulating one\047s self")
}' export-14.csv > outfile10
```

and that would be a much better starting point for whatever it is you're trying to do next.